# Will Apple Approve of iOS Cordova Apps?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I developed in and published a game to the Play Store made with the Phaser gaming engine and Cordova. When this game is good enough, I would like to publish it to the App Store, but I've read that Apple denies apps that use the Cordova framework. Is this true?

Comment: This is not true as I had an app (made with the phonegap build service which is essentially cordova) on the Apple store. But you must make sure the design meets Apple's standards.

Comment: When do you made  a appe ? In this year or before ?

Comment: I just took it off the app store recently. It was on there from March 2017 to November 2018

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortunately this is untrue :) I have published three separate Phaser games for both iOS and Android in Cordova.

There is a [known bug](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/83570?start=15&tstart=0) with the iOS simulator that will often cause performance issues for Cordova applications (has to due with some GPU stuff). When you push your application for review in iOS, just let your tester know as he / she may or may not be aware of the issue. I was denied a handful of times due to performance issues in the simulator but on every device it ran completely fine. Feel free to take a look at the game I most recently published made with Phaser and Cordova [Bubble Bounce Heroes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bubble-bounce-heroes/id1353178687?mt=8)

Comment: I seen your game. It has been good. Can you say me witch tool did you use, for Creating the  skins and Level as well ? Thanks !

Comment: @Cosss I used Adobe Illustrator to do all of the character/game design and I used texture packer to generate the spritesheets